# Divide dataframe into list of rows containing all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, rows

From dataframe sructured like this

```
   A B
 0 1 2
 1 3 4
```

I need to get list like this:

```
[{"A": 1, "B": 2}, {"A": 3, "B": 4}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   ['D', 'E', 'F']])

df.values.tolist()
```

output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

##### other options

```
df.T.to_dict('list')
{0: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 1: ['D', 'E', 'F']}

df.to_dict('records')
[{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'},
 {0: 'D', 1: 'E', 2: 'F'}]
```

Comment: I have a new issue now. It occurs to me that I not only need the list of rows, I also need each row to be a dictionary with column value as a key and row value as value. Is it better to create a new issue?

Comment: What would be the exact output using my example as input? Do you want: `df.T.to_dict('list')` -> `{0: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 1: ['D', 'E', 'F']}`?  Or maybe: `df.to_dict('records')` -> `[{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, {0: 'D', 1: 'E', 2: 'F'}]`?

Comment: I mean, if I have dataframe:
{"A": [1, 3], "B": [2, 4]}
I need to get list like this [{"A": 1, "B": 2}, {"A": 3, "B": 4}]

Comment: Please provide an explicit DataFrame constructor (like I didi in my answer) if my above options don't suit you (ideally edit your question)

Comment: OK, then what I already provided ;) `df.to_dict('records')`